# A function $f$ is analytic in the disk $\Delta=\Delta(0,1)$ and admits the estimate $|f(z)|\leq c(1-|z|)^{-n}$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$, where $n$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

**A function $f$ is analytic in the disk $\Delta=\Delta(0,1)$ and admits the estimate $|f(z)|\leq c(1-|z|)^{-n}$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$, where $n$ is a positive integer and $c>0$ is a constant. Show that $|f'(z)|\leq 2^{n+1}c(1-|z|)^{-n-1}$ for every $z$ in $\Delta$. (Hint. For fixed $z$ in $\Delta$ consider $f$ in the disk $\Delta(z,r)$, where $r=(1-|z|)/2$ )**

I am trying to use Cauchy Estimatives to solve this problem:

[image]

Taking into account the suggestion then $r=(1-|z|)/2$ and taking $m=c(1-|z|)^{-n}, z_0=z, k=1$, we arrive at that $|f'(z)|\leq 2c(1-|z|)^{-n-1}$ but this is not the desired result, how can I do to get what they ask me for? Could anyone help me, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: You've misstated the problem.

Comment: @zhw.  Why.....?

Comment: The maximum modulus principle implies that $f$ is identically $0$.

Comment: @user425181 You want $|f(z)| \le (1-|z|)^{-n}.$

Comment: @mrf  Why......?

Comment: @zhw. why c=1 ?

Comment: Yes the $c$ should be there.